# How do I overwrite a page template?

Tags: theming, commerce

I created a bunch of products, but I need to style them per the designer's design. I know that I have to overwrite the template from `/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/product/templates/commerce-product.html.twig` but where do I put it in my theme?

Does it go to the root of my templates folder? What is the correct way to style the single product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, just create a **copy** of **commerce-product.html.twig** from the product module in commerce to **your theme's template** directory.

for more instruction to visit https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/displaying-products/theme-product.

Comment: Right, I understand that but I'm asking if it goes to the root of the theme templates folder?

Answer (score 0):

@Amy Ling

The best practice for this use case is, in your theme templates folder create a product folder and create a copy of commerce-product.html.twig from the product module in commerce directory.

Eg: web/themes/custom/custom_theme/templates/product/commerce-product.html.twig

for more instruction to visit https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/displaying-products/theme-product.